# Greensock.js (GSAP) Version of Metafizzy Isotope.js (Masonry)

Tags: animation, jquery-isotope, gsap

Is there an equivalent Greensock (GSAP) implementation or plugin that has similar behaviors to Metafizzy's Isotope.js (Masonry layout). Specifically, I have implemented a series of card and card promotion animations in isolation. I am now at the point of merging these into a single prototype. I am working behind a colleague who put together a separate prototype using Isotope that supports card shuffling even with cards "growing" to different states. I am unifying both internal efforts. Before I engage on GSAPifying Isotope, I would like to know if there is an existing or similar implementation that I can leverage.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Chris

Comment: Share with the world when its ready ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still googling this, a quick solution to have gsap render the isotope animations is using the jquery-gsap-plugin that can be downloaded [at their website](http://greensock.com/jquery-gsap-plugin). It needs to be added after all the other libraries, for example:

```
<script src="js/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.gsap.min.js"></script>
```

What this does is override all the jQuery.animate() methods - which is awesome. There are some exceptions however that are listed on the website as well.

Now the only thing that is left to do is tell isotope to use jQuery as the animation engine, details can be found in the [documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/docs/options.html#animationengine).

```
$('#grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  layoutMode: 'fitRows',
  //etc
  animationEngine: 'jquery'
});
```

And viola! The only caveat here that jQuery is required, so for anyone using pure vanilla or whatever will have to override the animations manually - how that's done is a whole other topic.